# How to change the text in the text-box using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

How to update the text of the existing textbox in a slide?

I tried the [following tutorial](https://www.upbuild.io/blog/inject-google-sheets-data-into-slides/) and build my own code but its not working and the text is not updating.

```
  function myFunction() {
       const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
       var slides = presentation.getSlides()
  
       slide_1 = slides[2] // go to slide 2
       slide_2 = slide_1.getShapes()
  
       slide_2.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{replace_this_text}}','yes')
       })
 }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your script, when the text box, which has the text of `{{replace_this_text}}`, is put to the page 2 in Google Slides, `{{replace_this_text}}` is replaced to `yes`. So I think that it is required to confirm your Google Slides for replicating your issue. How about this?

Comment: yes that's what I want to do  but its not working

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that it is required to confirm your Google Slides and the script for replicating your issue. Can you provide the sample Google Slides including your script for replicating your issue?

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I did tried to recreate another slide that I can share but upon testing it works, checking my original work -it seems that the text box has other characters that why it was not found by the app-script. The issue is resolved. thank you!

Comment: This is not my experience - if your text box caontians e.g. `Hello, I am a textbox` and you perform the request `shape.getText().replaceAllText('box','container')` - this also works.

Answer (score 0):

the text on the replace text is strict, I checked the text box on the slide and adjusted it.

The text box should contain ONLY the exact that we wish to update.